# How can I print the files affected by a command-line substitution?

Tags: ruby

I am running the following Ruby-command from the command-line.

```
ruby -i -pe "gsub /2013/, '2014'" *
```

How can I make the command print the number/names of the files changed?

Comment: Please at least attempt to run a command once before disapproving it. It runs fine.

Comment: I would not disapprove it if I did not try, it does not work, it would be better to use pure `bash` for a task like this, or write this in pure ruby instead of attempting to use ruby as a unix utility

Comment: It runs cleanly as a simple copy & paste for me, I guess we're just using different Ruby versions then (2.1 here). I see your point, but the `sed` version on OSX is kind of buggy, and I guess the ruby one-liner options exist for a reason, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind a Perl solution to your one-liner request?

```
perl -i -pe '$f{$ARGV}++ if s/2013/2014/g; END {print STDERR (join " ", (keys %f, scalar(keys %f))), "\n" }' *
```